# jQuery image click function has no effect

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a situation where only the first click of an image works, the second time when clicked the other function doesn't run.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('#temp_container img').click(function(){
     var img = $('#temp_container img').attr('src');
     $('#temp_container2').append('<img src="'+img+'">');
   });

   $('#temp_container2 img').click(function(){
     alert('works');
   });
});
</script>

<div id="temp_container">
   <img src="http://cdn-images.farfetch.com/10/62/22/35/10622235_3103339_170.jpg">
</div>
<div id="temp_container2"></div>
```

When you click on the image in div `temp_container`, the image is duplicated and appended to `temp_container2`, when clicking on the image in div `temp_container2` an alert should be executed. But for some reason this doesn't execute when run. I've been stuck on this issue for hours.

Thanks

Comment: Look at delegating events in jQuery - since you are declaring the 2nd listener before there is any content in #temp_container2 you won't be able to bind onto it directly at that point.

Comment: Since dom is updated... you will have to use on() method... check event delegation

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need event delegation using `on()` as you are adding elements dynamically.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/H57xr/)

```
$('#temp_container2').on('click', 'img', function(){
   alert('works');
});
```

While adding elements in `$('#temp_container2')` you probably need to use `$(this).attr('src')` instead of `$('#temp_container img').attr('src')`

```
 $('#temp_container img').click(function(){
  var img = $('#temp_container img').attr('src');
  $('#temp_container2').append('<img src="'+img+'">');
});
```

**Delegated events**

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: +1 Was answering the same, but you did it already so just added a demo, so hope you don't mind :)

Comment: Thanks for the really helpful reply. I've been testing this and I noticed that if there is another div above the temp_container2, then the on() doesn't seem to work

http://jsfiddle.net/H57xr/

Comment: You have pasted same link the one in the answer, and probably had to give some other link?

Comment: Actually I managed to get it working by chaining div's together in the selector. Thanks for the great help!  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#temp_container img').click(function(){
```

Should be

```
$('#temp_container').click(function(){
```

Or you can create a new div for the image itself, this makes it easier.